# Trigger que alimenta uma tabela com informação da outra MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Tenho um banco de dados em MySQL com as tabelas de Estoque, Vendas e Ite_Vendas.

Ao realizar uma venda registro informações nas tabelas Vendas e Ite_Vendas, mas quero pegar uma informação da tabela Estoque e registrar na Ite_venda.

Segue a estrutura da banco:

```
Tabela Produto
CODPRODUTO  int(11)
CODGRUPO    int(11)
CODSUBGRUPO int(11)
CODTRIBUTACAO   int(11)
COD_BARPRODUTO  varchar(30)
CODFORNECEDOR   int(11)
NOMPRODUTO  varchar(80)
NOM_IDEPRODUTO  varchar(80)

Tabela Ite_Venda
CODBALCAO_ITEVENDA  int(10) unsigned
CODBALCAO_VENDA int(11)
CODPRODUTO  int(11)
CODBAR_PRODUTO  varchar(30)
NOMPRODUTO  varchar(80)
QTDPRODUTO  decimal(10,4)
VAL_TOTBALCAO_ITEVENDA  decimal(10,4)
VAL_ITEBALCAO_ITEVENDA  decimal(10,4)
VAL_ACRBALCAO_ITEVENDA  decimal(10,4)
VAL_DESBALCAO_ITEVENDA  decimal(10,4)
```

Eu preciso criar um trigger que ao gravar na tabela Ite_Venda eu possa pegar o campo COD_BARPRODUTO na tabela Produto e inserir na tabela Ite_venda no campo CODBAR_PRODUTO.

Comment: O que você já tentou até agora e quais problemas você encontrou?

Comment: @Caffé eu ainda não tentei uma outra alternativa, estou pensando em fazer desta forma pois trato no banco ao invés de tratar no sistema e desafogo um pouco de fazer tudo, e com esta função posso fazer outras funções utilizando o mesmo processo.

Comment: ao gravar na tabela Ite_Venda você ainda não tem o COD_BARPRODUTO ? se tem então não precisa de trigger e sim melhorar o seu insert, caso nesse instante você não tem o COD_BARPRODUTO me diga como você vai pegar ele na tabela Produto se não sabe qual é o código!

Comment: @MaisonSakamoto Fiz por meio do meu sistema meio e não por meio do Banco de Dados.

Comment: @ClaytonQuintiliano se fez por meio de sistema, então é sabido o COD_BARPRODUTO? então passa ele no insert, não precisa de trigger

Comment: Foi isso que fiz, não estava trazendo no pesquisar no banco mas alterei a programação e embuti este campo também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abandonei a função e fiz por meio do software mesmo.